# SFML Sound not playing (Operation not permitted)

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

So I was trying out the [SFML tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/audio-sounds.php) for playing a sound from a local file and came across a weird bug. Whenever I call the `playSound` function no sound is played and I get an error that I can't find the solution to:

`[ALSOFT] (EE) Failed to set real-time priority for thread: Operation not permitted (1)`

The strange thing is that if I do the same thing in the `main` function the sound is played. What is going on here? Here are the only files used in the project, the .wav is just a simple sound file:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

void playSound() {
    sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
    if (!buffer.loadFromFile("1-retro-arcade-casino-notification.wav"))
        return;
    sf::Sound sound;
    sound.setBuffer(buffer);
    sound.play();
}

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Notification test");

    sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
    if (!buffer.loadFromFile("1-retro-arcade-casino-notification.wav"))
        return -1;
    sf::Sound sound;
    sound.setBuffer(buffer);
    sound.play();

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered) {
                char key = static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode);
                
                if (key == 'p') {
                    playSound();
                }

                if (key == 'q') {
                    window.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
all:
    g++ -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -o main main.cpp
```

Answer (score 4):

The sound data is not stored directly in [`sf::Sound`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sound.php) but instead in the [`sf::SoundBuffer`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1SoundBuffer.php). This class encapsulates the audio data, which is basically an array of 16-bit signed integers (called "audio samples").

Sounds (and music) are played in a separate thread. This means that you are free to do anything you want after calling
[`void play()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sound.php#a2953ffe632536e72e696fd880ced2532), except destroying the sound or its data - which you are currently doing.

This is because you have declared your `sf::SoundBuffer buffer;` inside `void playSound()`, and subsequently, the sound data gets destroyed as it goes out of scope after returning from `void playSound()`.

To fix your problem, don't declare sf::SoundBuffer in the function. You could just declare it outside the main function, or even pass it as a parameter to playSound().

See the [relevant documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/audio-sounds.php) for info.